# How can I draw a neural network in my question?

Tags: support, math-display, images

I would like to draw a neural network. How can I do this in Cross Validated? Do I have to upload a picture or include a link? Or is there a more elegant way?

The same problem appears to other networks such as Bayesian Networks and Markov Networks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless there is some way to write HTML code to generate an image (which would seem like too much trouble to me anyway), you need to make a figure and upload it.  Any software tool that will let you create a figure and output it to a supported file type, e.g., .png, can be used.  For what it's worth, I find using the tools in PowerPoint convenient for that sort of thing.

Comment: (+1) NB Stack Exchange uses Markdown which ["only supports a very strict subset of HTML"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help).